# LUKS passphrase over ssh is not working

Tags: ssh, raspbian, cryptsetup, headless, dropbear

I am trying to decrypt a fully encrypted system using LUKS over SSH. I followed [stinky parkia's guide to unlocking device over ssh](https://stinkyparkia.wordpress.com/2014/10/14/remote-unlocking-luks-encrypted-lvm-using-dropbear-ssh-in-ubuntu-server-14-04-1-with-static-ipst/).

However, the password is not working. I am able to reach the prompt to enter the passphrase but it's simply not accepting the correct password.
Error: `cryptsetup: cryptsetup failed, bad password or options?`,

I type the same password with a keyboard attached directed with the Pi4 and it works.

I little more research showed `initramfs` option is required in `crypttab`.

Updated `crypttab`:

```
# <target name> <source device>     <key file>  <options>
sdcard  /dev/mmcblk0p2  none    luks,initramfs
```

However, the password is still not working over SSH.

Any hints on what I am possibly doing wrong?

Details:

1. uname -a: Linux raspi 6.1.21-v8+ #1642 SMP PREEMPT aarch64
2. OS: Raspberry OS lite
3. cryptsetup --version: cryptsetup 2.3.7

---

Update #1: Found similar instructions on a [linuxconfig.org blog](https://linuxconfig.org/introduction-to-crypttab-with-examples), same problem.

Update #2:
I thought the keyboard layout is different, but I typed the password in plain text and all characters are as expected.

Comment: I think it's one of these cases where the kernel can only return a numeric error code that doesn't convey much information, and the only place where it can convey information is in logs. So check the kernel logs with `dmesg`.

Comment: Hi @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil', I tried to look at the logs at the time of login attempts. But `dmesg` does not have any cryptsetup related logs.
Do I need to enable the logs somewhere?